# Filter generic list with array values in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an array of Colours Name and a Generic List of Products. I want to filter List which contains only products with the colours name in array same as Sql Like operator. e.g. '%Red%' .
my code is following

```
Public Class Item
        Public Property ItemID() As Integer
        Public Property ItemName() As String
        Public Property RetailPrice() As Double
        Public Property Colour() as String
End Class

Dim ColourNames() As String = {"Red", "Blue", "Black", "Green"}
Dim filteredList = (From i In listItems Where i.ItemName.Contains(ColourNames)).ToList
```

Comment: If you post the structure of your `Products` (class?), the answers will more precisely address the *issue*.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I've updated my example to match your updated question

Based on your example it looks like you intend ListItems to be the generic collection that contains your "Products".

Take your original ListItems Array and add the `where()` method to execute a LINQ query and get back only objects that match on the property from your ColourNames() Array.

```
    Dim ColourNames() As String = {"Red", "Blue", "Black", "Green"}
    Dim FilteredList = ListItems.Where(Function(i) ColourNames.Contains(i.Colour)).ToList
```

The `Where()` method will only return objects where the condition you specified is true.  It loops through your ListItems and evaluates each current object (represented as `i` in this example because thats what you used in your question but you can use any variable name) to see if the colour property is contained in the ColourNames array.

If you need the contains method to be case-insensitive you just add a `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` overload to it.  This will better mirror the functionality you'd get from LIKE in SQL.

```
Dim FilteredList = ListItems.Where(Function(i) ColourNames.Contains(i.Colour, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList
```

Comment: thanks for your cooperation. it search same matching word only. i need the whole items which contain searchable text. for example , i want to search red paint with 're pa'. is it possible in linq?